# I2C level translation mosfets obtainable to hobbyists

Tags: i2c, components, protection

Based on this [AN for level translation and overvoltage protection for I2C buses](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf), I am looking for a recommendation for a suitable mosfet that is obtainable for hobbyists.

The recommended BSN20 and its replacement part BSN20BK are impossible to get hold of for me. Are there any common-place alternatives for a 3.3V I2C bus? (I am looking for at least 30V drain-source voltage for overvoltage protection.)

I realise that I am skirting quite close to a "sourcing question" with this but hope somebody will take it in the spirit it is intended and can recommend an equivalent product for what is surely a fairly common problem.

Comment: And all the devices on your I2C bus tolerate 30V overvoltage without clamping it? You must be dabbling in a very strange industrial field not yet invented.

Comment: The big Chinese internet shops have plenty of I2C level translator modules.

Comment: You are not "skirting quite close", you are asking a 100 % recommendation question. You should have asked for the characteristics that such as MOSFET would need.

Comment: @Asmyldof No my I2C devices do not tolerate 30V but I am more willing to replace them than I would be to replace my master.

Comment: @CL. Thanks. However, I already know the characteristics I need. (The AN gives these.) They even recommend a device that would work. - The problem is finding devices that have the characteristics AND are obtainable to a hobbyist.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Thank you so much! I should have thought of that. I now found indeed a whole raft of them... You only find what you explicitly search for on these sites. - Do you have any experience what mosfets they typically use? I was wondering about the drain-source voltage for these modules.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Never mind. I found a seller where I could just about make out the surface markings: J1 - I guess that is BSS138. In this case, V_DS would be ok for me. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @ARF Use the parametric search of some large distributor (e.g., DigiKey). The devices available in the largest numbers are also most likely to be found elsewhere.

Comment: @CL. Great idea. I always sorted by price checking their availabiltiy of each with the "chinese online shops" in turn. It was a hopeless endeavour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSS138 maybe?
Vgs below 2V and Vgs max 50V.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. The "chinese internet shops" agree with you: On some of their modules one can read the markings: J1 (This seems to also be the markings for BSS138.)

Answer (score -1):

all it is asking is a logic level mosfet with a body diode, :)

plenty to choose from. I would use 2n7000/7002 but that's just because I have them in my junk box.

Comment: Wrong logic level: the 2N700x is designed for 5 V, and not guaranteed to work at 3.3 V.